# Define x when x + 100 = y. x=y*0,12 Is it possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of values that equal a total value (y). part of the list is (x). x is equal to 12 percent of y. What is x?

Comment: Do you mean the other (non-$x$) part of the list is $100$ total?

Comment: $x=100/(1-0.12)-100$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That works perfectly.